# Embed a scripting language inside Go

Tags: scripting, go, embedding

Is it possible to embed a language inside Go? I need it to create plugins inside my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the first, I'll explain cgo. Go provides API to export values into C language.

http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/

For example, you can export string as `char*` like below.

```
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
static void myputs(char* s) {
    puts(s);
}
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    s := "hello world"
    C.myputs(C.CString(s))
}
```

So you need to write functions to access C library. But there are some packages to use script languages. See:

https://github.com/mattn/go-mruby

https://github.com/mattn/go-v8

Or if you don't want to use C language. You can use native go language like otto

https://github.com/robertkrimen/otto

https://github.com/mattn/anko

Comment: No one says whether go is scripting language or not. Question is how to embed scripting languages in go. For example, the code above read a file and execute, it will be runtime of scripting language. You can see go-mruby, go-v8, otto, anko above.

Comment: This is not explaining about go-mruby. Just explaining what cgo is. See this entry "Or if you don't want to use C language. You can use native go language like otto".

Comment: bits modified explanation. How about this>

Answer (score 39):

I found the list on [Virtual Machines and Languages](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Projects#virtual-machines-and-languages).

- [Gelo](https://github.com/chrislusf/gelo) - Extensible, embeddable interpreter
- [GoForth](https://github.com/ArtemTitoulenko/GoForth) - A simple Forth parser
- [GoLightly](https://github.com/feyeleanor/GoLightly) - A flexible and lightweight virtual machine with runtime-configurable instruction set
- [Golog](https://github.com/mndrix/golog) - Prolog interpreter in Go
- [Minima](https://github.com/opesun/minima) - A language implemented in Go.
- [RubyGoLightly](https://github.com/feyeleanor/RubyGoLightly) - An experimental port of TinyRb to Go
- [forego](https://github.com/unixdj/forego) - Forth virtual machine
- [go-python](https://github.com/sbinet/go-python) - go bindings for CPython C-API
- [GoEmPHP](https://github.com/mikespook/goemphp) - This package is built for Embedding PHP into Go.
- [goenv](https://github.com/smyrman/goenv) - Create an isolated environment where you install Go packages, binaries, or even C libraries. Very similar to virtualenv for Python.
- [golemon](https://github.com/nsf/golemon) - A port of the Lemon parser-generator
- [goll1e](https://github.com/realistschuckle/goll1e) - An LL(1) parser generator for the Go programming language.
- [golua](https://github.com/afitz/golua) - Go wrapper for LUA's C API
- [golua-fork](https://github.com/xenith-studios/golua) - A fork of GoLua that works on current releases of Go
- [gotcl](http://code.google.com/p/gotcl/) - Tcl interpreter in Go
- [ngaro](https://github.com/db47h/ngaro) - An ngaro virtual machine to run retroForth images
- [otto](https://github.com/robertkrimen/otto) - A JavaScript parser and interpreter written natively in Go
- [monkey](https://github.com/realint/monkey) - Embed SpiderMonkey, the Mozilla JavaScript engine, in your Go program.
- [go-v8](https://github.com/idada/go-v8) - V8 JavaScript engine bindings for Go
- [gomruby](https://github.com/AlekSi/gomruby) - mruby (mini Ruby) bindings for Go
- [LispEx](https://github.com/kedebug/LispEx) - A dialect of Lisp extended to support for concurrent programming, written in Go.

Update:

- [Tengo](https://github.com/d5/tengo) - a small, dynamic, fast, secure script language for Go. (similar syntax with Go)
- [glua](https://github.com/RyouZhang/go-lua), [GoLuaJit](https://github.com/antonvolkoff/goluajit), [gijit](https://github.com/gijit/gi), and [others](https://github.com/rickcrawford/go-lua-test) - LuaJIT, one of fastest JIT implementation
- [Elsa](https://github.com/elsaland/elsa) - Typescript and Javascript, based on [QuickJS](https://bellard.org/quickjs/), same person who creates qemu, ffmpeg, tcc

Update 2:

- [Anko](https://github.com/mattn/anko) - Golang-like syntax
- [Binder](https://github.com/alexeyco/binder) - Seamless lua binding, uses [gopher-lua](https://github.com/yuin/gopher-lua)
- [Cel-Go](https://github.com/google/cel-go) - C-like syntax
- [Ecal](https://github.com/krotik/ecal) - Golang-like syntax
- [Expr](https://github.com/expr-lang/expr) - Golang-like syntax
- [Gentee](https://github.com/gentee/gentee) - strong-typed procedural language, used for shell-scripting-like use case
- [Gisp](https://github.com/jcla1/gisp) - LISP-like syntax
- [Goja](https://github.com/dop251/goja) - pure Go, ecmascript 5.1 interpreter
- [gval](https://github.com/PaesslerAG/gval) - math expression evaluator, not a complete language
- [prolog](https://github.com/ichiban/prolog) - another prolog interpreter
- [purl](https://github.com/ian-kent/purl) - perl interpreter
- [starlark](https://github.com/google/starlark-go) - python-like syntax

Comment: From your link, `meme` is written in C. **EDIT**: nevermind, I see now the `go` and `go1` branches - the author seems to be writing it in both languages?!

Comment: At the time of writing this comment, `Golog` unfortunately was archived by the maintainers. Also, it would be great to list which are Pure Go implementations, and which require CGO to launch external C libraries.

Answer (score 11):

[goja](https://github.com/dop251/goja) - ECMAScript 5.1(+) implementation in Go.

Comment: On average 6-7 times faster than otto. That's substantial.

Answer (score 4):

One that is very nice to use, but wasn't mention above: [`gopher-lua`](https://github.com/yuin/gopher-lua), a Lua 5.1 VM:

```golang
L := lua.NewState()
defer L.Close()
_ = L.DoString(`print("hello")`);
_ = L.DoFile("hello.lua");
```

Comment: `gopher-lua` is indeed very nice to use, especially taking into account that is a Pure Go implementation (no CGO, no external C libraries to link) which should run anywhere where Go is supported. Additionally, you can add a layer to simplify most calls to and from GopherLua: https://layeh.com/gopher-luar; this allows using Go channels in Lua, for example. Both packages get reasonably regular updates. However, `gopher-lua` is currently restricted to Lua 5.1. If you absolutely need another version of Lua, you'll have to stick to one of the packages based on popular C libraries.